# Error in Jquery and Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I write the code for uploading image in local machine in ajax and jquery. And if condition is not executed.

Here is the fnUploadImage script.

```
function fnUploadPhoto()
{
var image = $("#txtUploadImage").val();

var objUploadImage = new Object();
objUploadImage.ImageName = image;
objUploadImage.UserID = <?php echo $_SESSION['UserId']; ?>

$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"db.php?UploadImage",
    data: {data:objUploadImage},
    dataType:"json",
    async:false,
    success: function(response)
    {
        alert(response.ErrorMessage);
        if(response.IsError)
            $("#errorUploadPhoto")[0].innerHTML = response.ErrorMessage;
        else
            $("#errorUploadPhoto")[0].innerHTML = response.SuccessMessage;
    },
    error:function(response)
    {
        alert("Error: " + response.ErrorMessage);
    }
});
}
```

And this function calls the db.php UploadImage function which is as follows:

```
function UploadImage($data)
{
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["txtUploadImage"]);
$extension = end($temp);
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
    {
        if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
        {
            die(json_encode(array("IsError" => true, "ErrorMessage" => "Error")));
            //echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
            json_encode(array("IsError" => true, "ErrorMessage" => "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"]));
        }
        else
        {
            if (file_exists("profile_images/" . $_FILES["file"]["txtUploadImage"]))
            {
                //echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
                json_encode(array("IsError" => true, "ErrorMessage" => "Filename already exists."));
            }
            else
            {
                if($_FILES["file"]["size"]/1024 < 20)
                {
                    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "profile_images/" . $_FILES["file"]["txtUploadImage"]);
                    //echo "Stored in: " . "profile_images/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
                    json_encode(array("IsError" => false, "SuccessMessage" => "Image uploaded successfully."));
                }
                else
                {
                    json_encode(array("IsError" => true, "ErrorMessage" => "Minimum image size is 20 kb."));
                }
            }
        }
    }
else
{
    //echo "Invalid file.";
    json_encode(array("IsError" => true, "ErrorMessage" => "Invalid file."));
}
}
```

When i run this script it shows in me the Error called undefined.
Please help me to solve this.

Comment: do you need quotes around the value for UserID. EG objUploadImage.UserID = "<?php echo $_SESSION['UserId']; ?>";

Comment: I only need userid. quotes are does not matter.

Comment: Which bit is showing you undefined? Is it the value of response.ErrorMessage? If so, you need to make sure your server code (ie your php script) returns a JSON string which includes the key ErrorMessage. EG {"ErrorMessage":"Some Error Message"}. If your PHP script doesn't return this construct, the variable will not exists, and therefore you will get undefined in your js code.

Comment: udefined what??? if it is undefined $ then probably you forgot to add jquery.js

Comment: See this for ajax file uploading : http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/uploading-files-with-ajax/

Answer (score 0):

quotes are metter here. If you dont use codes it understands it is a variable which is undefined

Comment: if ((($data[$_FILES["file"]["type"]] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg") 

But it is not checked this condition.
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))

Comment: It is not checked this condition.

Answer (score 0):

the `error` function on `$.ajax` is called when there was a problem with the request. However, you are using the expected results of the script running successful, but returning an error:

```
error: function(response) {
    alert("Error: " + response.ErrorMessage);
}
```

`response.ErrorMessage` will not be set (only in the `success` callback), because that's something you return when the request was successful, although the logic inside the request may return an error, but that'sw hat you are handeling in the `success` callback.

[This is the way to catch an erroneous call](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

```
error: function(xhr, status, error) {
    alert("Error: " + status + ' ' + error);
}
```

as noted in the comments, this line is also faulty:

```
objUploadImage.UserID = <?php echo $_SESSION['UserId']; ?>;
                                                needs a ; ^
```

if the `UserId` is not an integer ID, it does need quotes.

Comment: OK. i got the error from UploadImage function but i think if condition of UploadImage function is not checked.

Comment: if ((($data[$_FILES["file"]["type"]] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))

It is not checked this if condition.

Comment: you got what error? pasting 4 lines of code in the comment field is not ready useful... update your question if you have additional info.

Answer (score 0):

Inspect that you are getting the file in `$_FILES["file"]` array or not

Answer (score 0):

I think its the jquery's old method "handleError" which has been removed from the jQuery since version 1.5, you can use this custom error handler inside your javascript, anywhere are jQuery:

```
jQuery.extend({
handleError: function( s, xhr, status, e ) {
    // If a local callback was specified, fire it
    if ( s.error )
        s.error( xhr, status, e );
    //Log it in the console
    else if(xhr.responseText)
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
}});
```